# Localizing time units

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Consider an `ActiveRecord` model called `Movie` that has a duration attribute representing the length of the movie in minutes. What is the best way to print out this attribute in my view?

I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
= l(@movie.duration, unit: :minutes) # Should return "105 minutes"
```

But it would be even more awesome if I could just write:

```
= l(@movie.duration)
```

or even

```
= @movie.duration
```

However, this would require some way of declaring what unit is used in the duration attribute which is just an integer in the database.

It seems that Rails I18n has a way of translating attributes, but only their names, not their values.

A solution that plays nicely with I18n is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason to complicate things here; you're not even converting between different units :

In your view :

```
<%= t :'models.movie.duration', :count => @movie.duration %>
```

In your `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  models:
    movie:
      duration:
        one: '%{count} minute'
        other: '%{count} minutes'
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails doesn't know the value is in minutes.

This functionality belongs in a helper, or (my preference) a decorator, with an I18N label.

Comment: What do you think about extending Fixnum to allow something like this `@movie.duration.format_as(:minutes)`

Comment: @NielsB. I think it's a pointless monkey patch that recklessly mixes concerns.

Comment: That's an opinion, but Rails already offers lots of convenience methods that you could argue are irrelevent to a class representing an integer. I'm not sure this functionality belongs in a helper, but perhaps in a model decorator. I'm not sure how to implement it cleanly though.

Intuitively, I think the model ougtha know what units its' attributes are defined in. I don't think some arbitrary show view should be concerned what unit is used in a particular attribute. If I decide later to use hours or seconds, the view will display things the wrong way.

Comment: @NielsB. Yes, Rails did conflate a lot of concerns, which is unfortunate. But things like `5.minutes` still aren't the view layer. Putting it in the model would be fine, although I'd make it *explicitly* part of the model *representation*, then, as opposed to a view layer afterthought.

Comment: *model representation* can you elaborate on that concept? How do you go about doing that in rails? Any links? I would like some nifty way of creating a manageable layer between my datamodel which is what ActiveRecord is and the views. Traditionally I add various formatting methods to the model, but it bloats the class and takes focus from what it is actually about: The data, the validation rules, the lifecycle and the associations.

Comment: @NielsB. Check out things like Draper for decorators. To keep units in the model, just do that, keep the units, although it might only be minutes. I'd have to think about it for longer to know what I'd do in this case, but it's likely I'd decorate for easy access to an I18N label if this is only for the view layer. Changes that affected how it's persisted would require changes no matter where the functionality lived.

Answer (score 1):

*I asked this question almost 7 years ago and there is still occasional activity on it.*

*So for those (junior) developers, who are thinking about this topic like I did, I would like to add a few thoughts.*

I think the question tries to tackle multiple problems. The first problem is that PostgreSQL does not have a native datatype for storing durations (at least not one that I am familiar with).

As a result, when working with durations we are forced to convert between a *duration* and a datatype that PostgreSQL provides. In my case, I used the integer type.

So there are two follow up questions.

#### What datatype should I use in the absence of a native duration type?

I would say either integer or decimal. It depends on the needs of the application and the quality of the data. If you prefer to store as minutes, but need (milli)second precision, use decimal. But generally, I find it easier to work with integers, so it is best to use a unit small enough that integers are precise enough.

#### How should I convert between the number type (integer/decimal) and the duration type within the application?

Depending on how you want to work with your data, I think it would be best to encapsulate the knowledge of how the duration converted into a database datatype instead of leaking this into the views (and elsewhere) in the application. If this knowledge leaks, it makes it a lot harder to change the underlying datatype later - for instance if PostgreSQL/Rails adds a better datatype.

So I would probably make a [value class](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/value-objects-in-ruby-on-rails-9df64bc8db34). This means making a duration class that is initialized with the database value, but can be queried and modified as a duration.

Simple example:

```
class Duration

  attr_accessor :seconds
  def initialize(seconds)
    @seconds = seconds
  end

  def minutes
    (seconds / 60.0).round
  end

  def minutes=(minutes)
    self.seconds = minutes * 60
  end

  def hours
    (seconds / (60.0 * 60)).round
  end

  def hours=(hours)
    self.seconds = hours * 60 * 60
  end

  def to_s(unit = :minutes) # Valid values are :seconds, :minutes and :hours.
    I18n.t("value_classes.duration.units.#{unit}", value: send(unit))
  end

end
```

if you combine this with custom accessors on your ActiveRecord class, then you've got a fairly solid encapsulation.

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord

  def duration
    Duration.new(duration_in_seconds) # Name of database attribute
  end

  def duration=(duration_instance)
    self.duration_in_seconds = duration_instance.seconds
  end

end
```

In a view:

```
<p>Duration: <%= @movie.duration %></p>
```

You may want to add some additional formatting methods to the Duration class, so you can choose between "127 minutes", "2 hours and 7 minutes" and "2:07" depending on how the designer wants it in the particular view.

This solution also contains accessors, so your controllers can do stuff like

```
@movie.duration = Duration.new.tap do |duration|
  duration.minutes = params[:movie][:duration_as_minutes]
end
```